# PHP's mysql_real_escape_string and MySQL Injection

Tags: mysql-real-escape-string

I have been trying to figure out how exactly **\x00, \n, \r, \, or \x1a** can cause an SQL Injection (as it is mentioned at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

I understand the idea of single quote and double quotes, but how and why I need to take care of the other items to make my query safe?

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering about the same question and I found the answer in the [C API documentation of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html), it states:

> Characters encoded are “\”, “'”, “"”, NUL (ASCII 0), “\n”, “\r”, and
>   Control+Z (\x1a). Strictly speaking, MySQL requires only that backslash and
>   the quote character used to quote the string in the query be escaped.
>   mysql_real_escape_string() **quotes the other characters to make them
>   easier to read in log files**.

It is also explained in [String Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html) that:

> The mysql client truncates quoted strings containing NUL characters if
>   they are not escaped, and Control+Z may be taken for END-OF-FILE on
>   Windows if not escaped.

The NUL character represents the end of a string in C language, so this can falsely terminate the input argument of the mysql client program. Same thing for `\x1a`, it marks the end-of-file under Windows (try `type test.txt` in a command prompt with a `\x1a` character in the middle of the file).

The main point is that an admin can miss important information in a log file if his log file reader doesn't show the data beyond one of these characters. But who still uses precarious `type` command or equivalent under Windows to read a log file anyway?

In other terms, there is no danger with `\n`, `\r`, `\0` or `\x1a` in PHP, other than potentially making a log file difficult to read.

As for the backslash, **\' OR 1==1** would be converted to **\\' OR 1==1** if it was not escaped too, cancelling the effect of the escaping of the quote.

Answer (score -1):

let's assume you have

```
$SQL="select * from mytable where myfield='$uservalue'"
```

**\ -> \**:

try `\' or 1=1; --'`, after escaping the quote, you would get `\\' or 1=1; --'` and the SQL would be `select * from mytable where myfield='\\' or 1=1; --'`

**\x00**

Not important for PHP, but for C

Sorry, too lazy for the rest.

Comment: hay, thanks a lot for the reply.. 
I pretty much had a similar idea about backslash **"\"**.

But what about **\n, \r, \x00, \x1a**?

Also please tell me more about the double dashes **--** you have used in your query example above.

Comment: I think the whole idea is only due to single quote... Even in your query if you remove single quote; backslash and double dashes and anything else will have no effect.

However, I an concerned about **\n, \r, \x00, \x1a** as it is mentioned in the php manual (http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).